# Deleted answer is migrated and undeleted

Tags: bug, status-norepro, migration, deleted-answers

I migrated this question:

https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/15937/applying-the-bayesian-information-criterion-for-stepwise-selection-algorithms-on

from Quant.SE to Cross Validated. Before I migrated the question the answer was deleted by the user. However, after migration the answer became undeleted instantly. This seems to be a bug to me.

Comment: The timeline/revision history for the linked answer does not show that it was ever deleted on the source site (Quantitative Finance) – nor the [corresponding post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/129848/148698) on the destination site (Stats/Cross Validated).

Comment: I don't remember the details now to be honest.

Comment: For now, I'll just tag the post as [status-norepro]. Feel free to update/make a new report if this crops up again.